# Access: "crosstab" query effect for non-numeric data

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, crosstab

I am using Access 2007 and need help creating a query. If this is crazy long, sorry! I figure the more details the better understanding. I am *not* a programmer--I hope someone will help.

I need to know how to collapse/summarize/roll up **non-numeric** data into a single row that shares a characteristic/value. What I want is **like** a crosstab query because I want unique cell values from different rows pivoted/displayed in columns along one row for that shared/common value. However, my data isn't numeric and it requires alpha column headings, which crosstabs prohibit.

**THE DATA:**

- Badge_code 24 is produced in 3 locations: 110, 210, and 320 (represents Chicago, Rockford, and St. Louis)
- Badge_code B9 in 2 locations: 110, and 280 (Chicago and Peoria)
- Badge_code C1 in 3 locations: 200 and 210 (Indianapolis and Rockford)

Each badge_code-location combination is in a separate row, 8 rows total.
The number of badge codes can/will grow.

**THE QUERY I'VE TRIED:**

```
Count(tbl_BadgeType.Badge_type_number) AS CountOfBadge_type_number
SELECT tbl_BadgeType.Badge_code
FROM tbl_BadgeType
GROUP BY tbl_BadgeType.Badge_code
PIVOT tbl_BadgeType.Location_production;
```

Badge_type_number is the primary key used to id each badge code-location use combo.

**RESULT:**

```
Badge Code     110   200   210  280  320
24             1           1         1
B9             1                1    
C1                   1     1
```

The column headings are numeric and can't be changed to location names in crosstabs and I want a "Yes" instead of a "1". (Obviously, they're 1s because it's a count function in the crosstab, which I don't really need...)

**DESIRED RESULT:**

```
Badge Code     Chicago  Indianapolis   Rockford  Peoria  St. Louis
24             Yes      No             Yes       No      Yes
B9             Yes      No             No        Yes     No
C1             No       Yes            Yes       No      No
```

**PROBLEM/QUESTIONS:**

4. A crosstab query in its strictest sense is not **quite** what I need, but I do not know how to simulate its "roll up" effect. It's the difference between 6 pages of obscurity and 1 page of useful clarity.
5. If a crosstab **is** the way to go, then I can't figure out how to get the "1" values to be displayed as a "Yes". I've used IIF statements in other queries and reports to "translate" 1/0 values to "Yes/No" but can't figure out where to put the IIFs in this query or its report.

Is this making sense? Am I asking too much? Is there hope for me? :^)

Comment: Could you post a sample of what tbl_BadgeType looks like, structure-wise, and a short sample of the relevant data in it? Your problem *feels* solveable, but its difficult to suggest solutions without knowing what the source data looks like. Thanks!

Comment: Also: is there another table that can be joined to Badge_code to grab "Chicago," "Illinois," etc?

Answer (score 1):

Wow! I wasn't expecting an answer so soon.

Here's the structure and sample data of pertinent fields of tbl_BadgeTypes :

```
Badge_code     Badge_description(both are Text fields)
01             Faculty/staff
04             College of Law
62             Student-Peoria
86             Visitor
B7             Police
```

The locations where a badge code is actually USED is in tbl_TokenInstance (a row for each instance of a token--badge, ID, etc. A badge code may be used by different locations; they're not exclusive. Pertinent data is:

```
  Instance_number(autonumber)  Prod_site_num(Integer)   Badge_code(text)
   1                            110                      B7
   3                            110                      B7
   4                            110                      B7
   27                           310                      04
   15                           210                      62
   21                           110                      62
   16                           110                      01
   22                           210                      01
   25                           310                      01
   31                           110                      86
   32                           120                      86
```

Last, the source list of production site numbers and descriptions is in list_ProductionSite:

```
  Production_site_number        Production_site_description
  110                           Chicago IDC
  120                           Chicago CS
  210                           Springfield IDC
  310                           Champaign IDC
  320                           Champaign CS
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so pending responses to the comments I left above, I can suggest some partial solutions (cleaner solutions may result, depending on what your table looks like):

**Problem #1: Numbers to Text**

If you have a table that can match [Location_production] to strings like "Chicago," than an inner join is all you need to make '110' appear as "Chicago." The third line of the query you tried would turn into something like:

```
FROM tbl_BadgeType AS T INNER JOIN tbl_Locations AS L ON T.Location_production = L.ID
```

You would then just crosstab on L.LocationName or whatever the actual text is.

**Problem #2: "1" to "Yes"**

Generally speaking, you could just swap a vb iif expression in to change the "1"s to "Yes"s

```
ProducesHere: iif([Badge_type_number]>0, "Yes","No")
```

You would need to change "Count()" to "Max()" or "Min()" in the top line of your query and possibly other changes, depending on what your data looks like.