# How to get value as header field in pivot table?

Tags: ms-access

I've been looking for this answer for hours without finding anything at all on this subject.

I'm trying to get a pivot table from the "Sells" table that displays :
- as header fields, the name of each seller in my shop
- as rows, each month of the year
- as data the sum of their sells for each month

The only issue I have is that the headers are populated with ID instead of the name of the sellers.

For example, instead of showing this :

```
Month    | Steve | Joe
January  | 5000$ | 600$
February | 400$  | 400$
```

It keeps showing the ID related to each seller:

```
Month    |   1   |   2
January  | 5000$ | 600$
February | 400$  | 400$
```

Here is my query :

```
TRANSFORM Sum(Sells.Ca) AS [Monthly sells]
SELECT DISTINCTROW Format$(Sells.DateSold,'mm - mmmm') AS Month
FROM Sells
GROUP BY Sells.DateSold
PIVOT Sells.Seller
```

Thank you very much for your help and your time.

**EDIT:**
As @WolfgangKais mentionned in the comments, I forgot to mention that the Seller field is a lookup field, that's why it only shows the first value of the lookup field, hence the ID and not the name.

Comment: You need to include Sellers table in the query to retrieve the names then pivot on the names field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access: "crosstab" query effect for non-numeric data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066569/access-crosstab-query-effect-for-non-numeric-data)

Comment: The `Seller` field is probably a "lookup field". You see the name but the ID is stored. Unfortunately, this lookup functionality doesn't work for the column headers of a crosstab query, therefore do what @June7 said and include the table with the seller's names and use these names as column headers.

Comment: Is this a multi-year database? Probably also need the year in the Row. Your Format doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. This is not a duplicate, @June7, at least not of the subject you linked. You are both right June7 and Wolfgang Kais, this field is a lookup field. I'll try your suggestion and get back to you as soon as I can. Thanks again!

Comment: Regarding the "multi-year database" question, it's not, that's why I'm just formatting months.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @June7 and @Wolfgang Kais, I had to include the Sellers Table in the query in order to get each seller's name instead of their ID, thank you very much for the lead.

This was done by :

1. Constructing a temporary table containing rows populated by sellers name, amount sold and date of sell:

   ```
   SELECT Sellers.Name AS Seller, Sells.Ca AS Amount, Sells.DateSold AS Month
   FROM Sells
   INNER JOIN Sellers ON Sells.Seller = Sellers.ID
   ```
2. Including this temporary table into my first pivot query (In the FROM part):

   ```
   TRANSFORM SUM(TempTable.Amount) AS [Monthly Sells]
   SELECT Format$(TempTable.Month, 'mm - mmmm') AS Month
   FROM(
        SELECT Sellers.Name AS Seller, Sells.Ca AS Amount, Sells.DateSold AS Month
        FROM Sells
        INNER JOIN Sellers ON Sells.Seller = Sellers.ID
   ) AS TempTable
   GROUP BY Temptable.Month
   PIVOT Temptable.Seller
   ```